# convert Platform::UIntPtr(windows runtime type) to void*

Tags: windows, c++-cx, uwp

I am developing an Universal windows App. Now I need to convert Platform::UIntptr to void* and vice versa.

Unfortunately there is no function such as ToPointer in the object of type Platform::UIntPtr so that I get get the pointer stored in the object and type casting is not working.

Please tell me how can I do this conversion.

Comment: You can't, it is an opaque type.  You need to post code that shows it being used.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot convert *Platform::UIntPtr* to *void**.

**Platform::UIntPtr** is defined by the Windows Runtime architecture and is built into C++/CX and it is for internal use only.

Can you be more specific about what's kind of scenario you need to convert the *Platform::UIntPtr* to void*?